# Cassandra Data Modelling approach

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I have below initially designed static column family in cassandra

```
create table APP_DATA (
CODE varchar, 

DATA varchar,

CREATED_DT timestamp,

REQUEST_TYPE int,

STATUS int,

..... #Some more columns ...,

PRIMARY KEY ((CODE,DATA),CREATED_DT))

 with clustering order by (CREATED_DT desc);
```

Now, I want to query the below

1)SELECT

```
SELECT * FROM APP_DATA WHERE CODE='1' AND DATA='1111111111';

SELECT * FROM APP_DATA WHERE CODE='1' AND DATA='1111111111' AND CREATED_DT<=dateof(now()) AND STATUS=0;

SELECT * FROM APP_DATA WHERE CODE='1' AND DATA='1111111111' AND CREATED_DT<=dateof(now()) AND STATUS=0 AND REQUEST_TYPE=9;
```

2)DELETE

```
DELETE FROM APP_DATA WHERE CREATED_DT+5<=sysdate;
```

How should I proceed with data modeling ? 
How should I design to make the above select and delete queries faster ?
Please guide ..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi First of all take CREATED_DT column out of PRIMARY KEY, and left with two column in PRIMARY KEY. Make CREATED_DT as a normal column and create secondary indexes to query.

Second to delete the data which is older than five days (CREATED_DT+5 <= sysdate) use [TTL](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_ttl_t.html) (Time to live) feature of Cassandra.

I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing. I thing your table looks good and you do need to take out CREATED_DT out of the primary key because you are grouping by it as DESC. And, in order to do that you have to make it a clustering column.

Secondly Cassandra practices  is a query driven methodology. Meaning you create a table to satisfy a query. Try to avoid creating Secondary indexes as much as you can and create tables instead to satisfy the query.

You DML should be based on partition key.

Comment: Can you group by without creating CREATED_DT as clustering column.

Comment: @Syed. In Cassandra only clustering columns can be grouped by. They are basically used for ordering criteria in the disk while Partition keys are used to group data.